# ReceiveMessage event showing data as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe in which there is a JavaScript function:

```
  function callParent(){
    parent.postMessage('closeModal','*');   
    return true;
  }
```

And other JavaScript function in my main page:

```
$(window).on('message',function(e){
console.log(e);
});
```

It's printing e but in e.data it's giving undefined. I was expecting data will be a String 'closeModal'.

How to get message String from iframe?

Comment: Try `console.log(e.originalEvent)` and see if your "data" property is there. jQuery creates its own event object, and that is what is passed to your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're passing is in

`e.originalEvent.data`

so on the main page:

```
$(window).on('message',function(e){
  console.log(e.originalEvent.data);
});
```

As `Pointy` commented jQuery creates its own event object.

If you were not using jQuery you would have had

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    console.log(e.data);
};
```